Sent BTC to change address instead of a receiving address; is it ok to just leave it like that or should I move the BTC to a receiving address?
I read this question, and although it helped clear things up, it didn't quite answer my question.
I inadvertently sent BTC to one of my electrum wallet's change addresses instead of a receiving address. I am asking if it is good enough to just leave the BTC in the change address, or would it be a better idea to move that BTC from the change address to a receiving address in the same wallet. Are there any negative implications of leaving BTC in a change address?

You can leave the coins in the change address and your wallet 'should' show them as a part of your balance. Your wallet should also choose to spend those coins when needed.
tl;dr, a change address is just another Bitcoin address and they are equally as safe to leave you funds in.

Not equally safe. It is safer, as Satoshi Nakamoto stated in Bitcoin whitepaper: "As an additional firewall, a new key pair should be used for each transaction to keep them from being linked to a common owner."
